# Difference in directions of charge and current.?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrons, electric-current, charge

I just dont understand that why does charge flow in a different direction as that if current when current is the rate of flow of charge.

Answer (score 1):

Long ago somebody decided that the direction of "conventional" current flow was the same direction as the direction of flow of positive charges.

In that convention the flow of negative charge in one direction is equivalent to the flow of positive charge (and hence the conventional current) in the opposite direction.

When introduced electricity usually deals with circuits which contain metal wires in which the mobile charge carriers are negative electrons.
This has lead to some people suggesting that the current direction should be the direction of the flow of negative electrons and there are even textbooks written using that convention.
That convention has failed to gain favour because mobile charge carriers are not exclusively negative and the fact that the majority of books are written using the direction of flow of positive charge convention.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing "flows" actually. Electrons transfer the electrical energy by hitting each other. And even if you consider flowing, only electrons free. Protons cannot because they're held strongly in nucleus.
About charge, textbooks usually refers it as positive. That means, we just take the opposite direction of electron flow as +ve charge (because electrons are negative)

Charge doesn't flow in a different direction, we assume +ve charge to flow opposite to electronic charge. This situation is hypothetical and trust me, neither do I know why we study like that.

Answer (score 0):

Charge is conserved, so the equation of continuity should be applied, . It states that the divergence of the current density J (in amperes per square meter) is equal to the negative rate of change of the charge density ρ (in coulombs per cubic metre),

[image]

> Current is the flow of electric charge. So if the divergence of J is positive, then more charge is exiting than entering the specified volume. If charge is exiting, then the amount of charge within the volume must be decreasing. This is exactly what the right side is a measure of - how much electric charge is accumulating or leaving in a volume. Hence, the continuity equation is about continuity - if there is a net electric current is flowing out of a region, then the charge in that region must be decreasing. If there is more electric current flowing into a given volume than exiting, than the amount of electric charge must be increasing.

You can find out more at [Maxwell's Equationn](http://maxwells-equations.com/equations/continuity.php), which goes through the derivation of the continuity equation.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of gauss theorem...When electron flows in a conductor it produces electric field inside it but according to gauss theorem electric field inside a conductor is zero... therefore current must have to flow in opposite direction to cancel the electric field produced by the electron...